Assign static IP to Kubevirt VM pod
I'm trying to assign a static IP address to a Kubevirt VM pod. My goal is to be able to access the pod using the static IP over the network outside of Kubernetes. Here's my config:
apiVersion: kubevirt.io/v1
kind: VirtualMachine
metadata:
  name: testvm
spec:
  running: false
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        kubevirt.io/size: small
        kubevirt.io/domain: testvm
    spec:
      domain:
        devices:
          disks:
            - name: containerdisk
              disk:
                bus: virtio
            - name: cloudinitdisk
              disk:
                bus: virtio
          interfaces:
          - name: default
            bridge: {}
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 512M
      networks:
      - name: default
        multus:
          default: true
          networkName: bridge-test
      volumes:
        - name: containerdisk
          containerDisk:
            image: quay.io/kubevirt/cirros-container-disk-demo
        - name: cloudinitdisk
          cloudInitNoCloud:
            userDataBase64: SGkuXG4=
---
apiVersion: "k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1"
kind: NetworkAttachmentDefinition
metadata:
  name: bridge-test
spec:
  config: '{
      "cniVersion": "0.3.1",
      "name": "bridge-test",
      "type": "bridge",
      "master": "kvbr0",
      "mode": "bridge",
      "ipam": {
        "type": "static",
        "addresses": [
          {
            "address": "10.120.224.45/23",
            "gateway": "10.120.225.1"
          }
        ]
      }
    }'

On the host I have bridge kvbr0 that is also in the 10.120.224.0/23 network.
This applies successfully. After I start the VM using virtctl start testvm, running virtctl console testvm shows nothing. kubectl get vmi shows testvm in phase Scheduling.

(In Kubernetes environments I'm used to using, the Kubernetes-internal network is completely isolated from the external network, and out-of-cluster calls can't reach the Pod IP addresses.  That makes it not particularly meaningful to assign static IP addresses to Pods or Services.  This seems like it's more related to system administration than programming per se and it might be more appropriate to ask this on another site.)
